# docker Windows 10 file sharing issue

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, windows-10

Windows 10 - Docker: 19.03.8

I thought i would try out Docker and started with the Microsoft .Net Core Web API sample provided by Microsoft.

It works for a Windows container, but i want to build for a Linux container.

When i enable Linux container and replace the Dockerfile with:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["VIPPostcode.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./VIPPostcode.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "VIPPostcode.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "VIPPostcode.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "VIPPostcode.dll"]
```

i get the error shown below, i have tried

- disabling Kaspersky.
- sharing the entire C: drive
- Enabling Edge features mode
- Rebooted

**Error:**

```
docker: Error response from daemon: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Filesharing has been cancelled","StackTrace":"   at Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<DoShareAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<ShareAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:line 47\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.HttpApi.Controllers.FilesharingController.<ShareDirectory>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.HttpApi\\Controllers\\FilesharingController.cs:line 21\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"}.
```

in case it helps the entire build output:

```
========== Checking for Container Prerequisites ==========
Verifying that Docker Desktop is installed...
Docker Desktop is installed.
========== Verifying that Docker Desktop is running... ==========
Verifying that Docker Desktop is running...
Docker Desktop is running.
========== Verifying Docker OS ==========
Verifying that Docker Desktop's operating system mode matches the project's target operating system...
Docker Desktop's operating system mode matches the project's target operating system.
========== Pulling Required Images ==========
Checking for missing Docker images...
Pulling Docker images. To cancel this download, close the command prompt window.
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim
Docker images are ready.
========== Warming up container(s) for VIPPostcode ==========
Starting up container(s)...
docker build -f "C:\Users\omega\source\repos\VIPPostcode\Dockerfile" --force-rm -t vippostcode:dev --target base  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=VIPPostcode" "C:\Users\omega\source\repos\VIPPostcode" 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  18.43kB

Step 1/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
 ---> 579be85d9bf6
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in a989f5bd43ea
Removing intermediate container a989f5bd43ea
 ---> ada3f994e957
Step 3/6 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 1ddc3c954d5a
Removing intermediate container 1ddc3c954d5a
 ---> a80514261699
Step 4/6 : EXPOSE 443
 ---> Running in 7fb6d8eb4fcb
Removing intermediate container 7fb6d8eb4fcb
 ---> 3d999f90edc5
Step 5/6 : LABEL com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio
 ---> Running in 596960e3491e
Removing intermediate container 596960e3491e
 ---> fdd4f65b0a34
Step 6/6 : LABEL com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=VIPPostcode
 ---> Running in ebc20702a8e1
Removing intermediate container ebc20702a8e1
 ---> 8ac00b24f93d
Successfully built 8ac00b24f93d
Successfully tagged vippostcode:dev
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Users\omega\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1" -Version vs2017u5 -RuntimeID linux-x64 -InstallPath "C:\Users\omega\vsdbg\vs2017u5"
Info: Using vsdbg version '16.6.20415.1'
Info: Using Runtime ID 'linux-x64'
Info: C:\Users\omega\vsdbg\vs2017u5 exists, deleting.
Info: Successfully installed vsdbg at 'C:\Users\omega\vsdbg\vs2017u5'
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Users\omega\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1" -Version vs2017u5 -RuntimeID linux-musl-x64 -InstallPath "C:\Users\omega\vsdbg\vs2017u5\linux-musl-x64"
Info: Using vsdbg version '16.6.20415.1'
Info: Using Runtime ID 'linux-musl-x64'
Info: Successfully installed vsdbg at 'C:\Users\omega\vsdbg\vs2017u5\linux-musl-x64'
docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\omega\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "C:\Users\omega\source\repos\VIPPostcode:/app" -v "C:\Users\omega\source\repos\VIPPostcode:/src/" -v "C:\Users\omega\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\omega\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro" -v "C:\Users\omega\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -v "C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -P --name VIPPostcode --entrypoint tail vippostcode:dev -f /dev/null 
docker: Error response from daemon: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Filesharing has been cancelled","StackTrace":"   at Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<DoShareAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<ShareAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:line 47\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.HttpApi.Controllers.FilesharingController.<ShareDirectory>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.HttpApi\\Controllers\\FilesharingController.cs:line 21\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"}.
See 'docker run --help'.
A non-critical error occurred while getting the container(s) ready. Your project(s) will continue to function normally. The error was: Docker command failed with exit code 125.
docker: Error response from daemon: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Filesharing has been cancelled","StackTrace":"   at Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<DoShareAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<ShareAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:line 47\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.HttpApi.Controllers.FilesharingController.<ShareDirectory>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.HttpApi\\Controllers\\FilesharingController.cs:line 21\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"}.
See 'docker run --help'.
If the error persists, try restarting Docker Desktop.
```

Answer (score 3):

You  have to add the path to folder to the restricted folders list in File Sharing menu explicitly:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out after a complete uninstall, reboot, reinstall, reboot  it works.  I have no idea what was wrong but at least it works now!

Comment: Maybe this helped too https://www.broispro.com/2020/05/30/500-messageunhandled-exception-filesharing-has-been-cancelled/

Answer (score 0):

just add path folder where docker yaml file to file sharing in Docker Setting